# Background-image style for inline image

Tags: html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

The style:

```
#image {
        background-image: url(website.com/img.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 90px;
    }
```

How could I get the same effect using a inline image in `<div id="image"></div>`?
When I use the background image, it fits perfectly inside the div but I need to use inline images for certain code

Comment: You mean to use `<img>` tag inside the `<div>`?

Comment: I have added a comment below

Comment: And what the problem with `<img>` tag? Please attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="image" style="background-image: url(website.com/img.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want to get the same style as when I would use a background image but using a <img> tag

Comment: Ah, well you'd have to start getting into javascript and adjust positioning and size. It's easiest to use `background-size: cover;` Why does it need to be an <img> tag?

Comment: Just found the answer, object-fit: cover; solved my problem

Comment: That property works, just be aware that property is CSS3 and isn't supported by older browsers. Glad you found a solution though!